# Why is nothing being passed to my overloaded function?

Tags: c#, .net, function, overloading

first poster here. To start things off, I'm using .NET 4.8 and C#. I'm having some issues with an overloaded function that doesn't seem to be getting any parameter input. Essentially what my functions are trying to do is take either a single object or a list of objects (all of a custom class 'Card') and determine if one of them has the same faction as the object calling the function. However, when I debug the the program, the first function works perfectly and as expected, but the second function doesn't seem to be getting any input at all; it gets an object with length 0.
'Factions' is a namespace-wide public enum; I don't think there are any problems there.

Class and function definition:

```
public class Card
{
    /* Constructors, variables, and other functions left out for simplicity */

    public bool SameFaction(Card card)
    {
        if (card.Faction.Equals(this.Faction))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public bool SameFaction(List<Card> hand)
    {
        foreach (Card card in hand)
        {
            if (card.Faction.Equals(this.Faction))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Implementation:

```
Card card1 = new Card(Factions.faction1);
List<Card> listOfCards = new List<Card>();
{
    new Card(Factions.faction1);
    new Card(Factions.faction2);
    new Card(Factions.faction3);
    new Card(Factions.faction4);
};

card1.SameFaction(new Card(Factions.faction1)); // Returns true
card1.SameFaction(listOfCards); // Returns false, and when debugging, shows input as being an object of length 0
```

Basically I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong, and also if there's a better way of doing this. I'm self-taught, so any and all suggestions are helpful. Thanks!

Comment: `new List<Card>(); {` - that `;` is suspicious

Comment: You are basically asking, why is `card.Faction.Equals(this.Faction)` returning `false` for every `factionN` you were added to your list. There is nothing to do with overloads. You can debug and check what's wrong.

Comment: @Mat Every `;` after `new Card()` is suspicious.

Comment: Makes me wonder if the collection initializer syntax was poorly-designed, since a single misplaced semicolon can completely change its meaning. A bit of a trap for novice coders!

Comment: @BradleySmith Well, in this case, VS will show a _"IDE0059 Unnecessary assignment of a value to 'listOfCards'"_ message, Idk if it will be helpful or not.

Comment: If you inspected this in the debugger at all you would see that `listOfCards` is indeed empty.

Comment: @Mat You were 100% correct. Those hide-and-seek semicolons :/ Thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is a single `;` too many

```
List<Card> listOfCards = new List<Card>();
{
    new Card(Factions.faction1);
    new Card(Factions.faction2);
    new Card(Factions.faction3);
    new Card(Factions.faction4);
};
```

This is two things, not one, since the first line ends in `;`. It creates an empty list and then there’s a block of code which creates objects without putting them anywhere.

This is probably what you meant:

```
List<Card> listOfCards = new List<Card>
{
    new Card(Factions.faction1),
    new Card(Factions.faction2),
    new Card(Factions.faction3),
    new Card(Factions.faction4)
};
```

Comment: yeah this is the answer. in the OP it creates a new list with 0 items, then within the {'s it creates a bunch of new cards without assigning them anywhere. To test, step through your calling function and see what is being sent to the function.